# What are the chances that Tyrannosaurus Rex could roar?

Tags: ethology, palaeontology

Tyrannosaurus Rex is now thought to have possibly had lips. Less of chance of it roar though I was told by a friend just because there are birds doesn’t mean they can’t.

Evolution isn't linear, just because one branch of a tree could/couldn't do something, doesn't mean 70+ million years later descendants could/couldn't do it too?

Comment: there's info on that here. https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2016/07/12/think-dinosaurs-roared-like-in-jurassic-park-the-truth-new-research-says-is-a-bit-wimpier/?utm_term=.868191bc02b2 The thoracic musculature uses bones that describe some kind of roar power if it is present.

Comment: birds and crocs can't that's called bracketing, which is not definitive but a good indicator.

Answer (score 3):

Careful now: T Rex was not a bird, it was a non-avian [theropod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theropoda). Birds are dinosaurs but not all dinosaurs are birds. In the same way, tigers are cats but not all cats are tigers.

The argument that T Rex could not roar is not only based on none of its closest relatives being able to as you seem to indicate. Dinosaurs (and by extension birds) are [archosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archosaur), a clade that includes crocodilians too and crocodilians are quite a bit more close to the basal form of archosaurs than T Rex was. Crocodilians can only sort of "hiss", not roar in the colloquial sense. And birds cannot roar. This is a decent start to a thought process but this isn't really the argument for why dinosaurs likely didn't roar in the past.

Researchers who have studied the potential vocalizations of prehistoric, non-avian dinosaurs have found indications that similar closed-mouth vocalization to those found in other living archosaurs are very probable: https://news.utexas.edu/2016/07/11/dinosaurs-may-have-cooed-like-doves

Closed-mouth vocalization is not really compatible with what people typically think of as roaring. It still allows a variety of sounds that don't necessarily (though perhaps probably) somewhat resembled crocodialian or simple bird vocalizations. So no, it's not *impossible* that some non-avian dinosaurs could roar but the current state of our knowledge is that they very likely could *not*.

Comment: so you are saying they couldn't roar at all since u say they could not in the end :(

Comment: I'm not claiming that they definitely could not. I'm saying that the current scientific consensus seems to be that they *probably* could not.

Comment: I guess they couldn't :(

Comment: Of course you have to ask yourself, if you scale a goose honk up to t-rex size, how different is it really from a roar.

Comment: a cooing T-rex :-)